# error in nodejs using sripe for payment for website

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, ejs

I am implementing a payment method in my e-commerce website using stripe and node.js , and I am not using a database only using JSON files to add my items to the website, but I am getting errors in ejs file. for rendering the page I used the fs module in node js. I wanted to know where I can define the items in ejs , or server , or HTML file

```
''' shop.ejs'''
   <div class="box-container">
            <% items.products.forEach(function(item){ %>
                <div class="box" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href="#" class="fas fa-shopping-cart shop-item-button"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fas fa-eye"></a>
                    </div>
                    <img class="image" src="/image/<%= item.imgName %>" alt="">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="price"> &#8377 <%= item.price %></div>
                        <h3 class="shop-item-title"><%= item.name %></h3>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                            <span> (50) </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
   <% }) %>

'''server.js'''
app.get('/shop', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data){
        if(error){
            res.status(500).end()
        }else {
            res.render('shop.ejs', {
                items: JSON.parse(data)
            })
        }
    })
})

'''error'''

 >> 172|     <% items.products.forEach(function(item){ %>

    173|         <div class="box-container" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">

    174|                 <div class="box">

    175|                     <div class="icons">


items are not defined
```

Comment: Can you show a better code snippet?

Comment: i edited the question i added codes

Answer (score -1):

Did you pass the `items` data object to the ejs `render` function?

Comment: how to do that?